# java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to port [7003] on host [VM_IP1]

Tags: cloudify

I have two Virtual Machines running cloudify-manager-1 (with VM_IP1) and cloudify-manager-2 (with VM_IP2).

After some days, the VMs goes down. Into the "2015-04-16~10.33-gigaspaces-esm_3-VM_IP1-20855.log" log file of the cloudify-manager-1 I can see the errors reported at the following link:

[2015-04-16~10.33-gigaspaces-esm_3-VM_IP1-20855.log](http://paste.openstack.org/show/204060/)

Moreover, il I can to conenct to the cloudify-manager-1 by the cloudify shell, I obtain the following error:

```
cloudify@default> connect 212.189.205.246

Failed to locate a lookup service in the cloud endpoint with discovery groups:[localcloud] and locators:[jini://VM_IP1:4174/, jini://VM_IP2:4174/] 
Operation failed.
```

whereas if I try to connect to the cloudify-manager-2, it works

```
cloudify@default> connect VM_IP2
Connected successfully
```

Can someone help me to understand where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Its not entirely clear what you mean by "the VMs goes down". The ESM error log indicates that this ESM instance tried to start but the port is opens (7003) is already in use.

This could indicate that there was an older instance of the ESM running on the same machine, and it is somehow stuck. This would cause Cloudify to try and start a new agent, assuming the old one is dead, but the old one is still holding the required port. Try checking for another instance of the ESM running on the same machine (or for whatever process that is holding the port).

As for the CLI errors, it seems like one of the VMs (VM_1) is suffering some sort of communication problem - it is not able to find the other services of the cloudify manager. The Manager VM_2 seems to be functioning, and still find the running services (which should be available on both manager).

Please be aware the Cloudify 2 has reached end-of-life. You may want to check out Cloudify 3.

Comment: Thank you Barak. With "The VMs go down" I want to say that the cloudify-manager VMs are not providing any Cloudify service (REST, WEBUI, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

Some days ago, I have only ran the following commands to restart the Cloudify processes and save the applications state:

```
cloudify@default> shutdown-managers -timeout 10 --verbose

cloudify@default> bootstrap-cloud --verbose -use-existing <openstack-cloud-driver-name>
```

To solve the error od the ESM, I have executed:

- `ssh` in both the cloudify-manager VMs
- killing of all the java processes (returned by `pgrep java`)
- `/root/gigaspaces/tools/cli/cloudify.sh`
- `cloudify@default> start-management -timeout 30 --verbose -cloud-file /root/gs-files/<openstack-cloud-driver-name>.groovy`

Now the cloudify-managers work, and the applications previously deployed work, too.